# Gulp.js + Ember + Common.js: Cannot set property 'exports' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I recently tried to use the gulp Gist posted [here](https://gist.github.com/simme/8931006):

Everything builds fine, but in the browser I get an error in the generated `templates.js` file:

```
global.Handlebars = require("handlebars");
module.exports = Ember.TEMPLATES["index"] = Ember.Handlebars.template(function anonymous(Handlebars,depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
```

The error claiming, basically, that 'module' is undefined...

I'm getting a strong feeling that I'm missing something extremely trivial here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think setting `module.exports` is Node specific, and not in the original CJS.

Comment: Are you sure that before you call module.exports you have already loaded your module loader?

Answer (score 0):

Because this causes the file to be wrap in some shim javascript:

```
'templates': {
    path: 'public/js/templates.js',
    exports: 'Ember.TEMPLATES'
},
```

Remove it and you'll be fine.

And requiring Ember in the prebundle is useless if you are also requiring it from your code.